# How to protect frontend and rest API with Keycloak

Tags: authentication, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I am very new to Keycloak server and want to use it to protect my front-end app and the backend rest API which are also open over the internet. So far what I understand and did is to create 2 clients on Keycloack, 1 is for frontend which used Client Protocol(openid-connect) with access type(Public) and then in client side i am using adopter to redirect the users to Keycloak login page and authenticate and get token. Now for the backend(rest-apis), I have created a separate client which again use Client Protocol(openid-connect) but with access type(confidential) and in Authentication Flow: both Browser Flow and Direct Grant Flow are direct grant and after that i get client-id and client-secret to call Keycloak rest api.

Now i want that when user are authenticated from frontend and get the token and send in header  request to my rest API, here i call some Keycloak rest api to verify this token by providing client_id and client_secret.

I am using following rest api from Keycloak to verify the token which i generated at frontend:

```
http://localhost:8120/auth/realms/evva_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
```

but result is getting like that:

```
{
    "active": false
}
```

It my be i am using some wrong api OR the whole archetecture to verify and protect my backend apis are not correct. Can someone help me to understand where is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

@user565 I found this medium post that works for me. I believe that you can benefit from it as well.

It basically creates two clients, one for the backend, and another for the frontend. The catch is that they share the same roles by leveraging the client scope, roles, and composite roles features.

Hope it helps: https://medium.com/devops-dudes/secure-front-end-react-js-and-back-end-node-js-express-rest-api-with-keycloak-daf159f0a94e